# Getting only the message of the status facebook php API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook php api. I want to get only the message (string) of the users status. In my code it's returning lots of fields but I want only to get message field. How can I do that?

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/400495666788117');
$response = $request->execute();
$graph = $response->getGraphObject();

echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graph, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

output :

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
    [backingData:protected] => Array
        (
            [id] => 400495666788117
            [from] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => *******
                    [name] => *******
                )

            [message] => aaa
            [updated_time] => 2015-03-02T11:59:12+0000
```

Comment: Please define the error or code what response you are getting

Comment: you can print only what you need with print $graph->message;

Comment: @NarendraSisodia i have already put that as output

Comment: If you are getting the answer as you desire than you have to try @MarcoMura answer

Comment: @MarcoMura i tried ur code its not working for me.

Comment: @MarcoMura it gives an error - " Notice: Undefined property: Facebook\GraphObject::$message in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\index.php on line 96  "

Comment: Improved code formatting and some typo/grammar tweaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `raw_response` and `json_decode` to get the message. This is assuming that you are querying for a single status. For multiple from a feed, you have to loop through the `data` element.

Single status

```
   $arrayResult = json_decode($response->getRawResponse(), true);
   $message = $arrayResult['message'];
```

Feed

```
$arrayResult = json_decode($response->getRawResponse(), true);
foreach($arrayResult['data'] as $post){
    $message = $post['message'];
    $post_time = $post['created_time'];
}
```